# Difficult search in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I search first in model (i know how to do this). And then search in this array for more concretence? As you see:

```
@articles = Article.find(:all, :conditions => { :ART_ID => @search.map(&:ARL_ART_ID)})
@a = @articles.find_all{|item| item.ART_ARTICLE_NR == search.upcase }
```

First i search in model, but thanks to my db) it have many wrong results, so i must to clarify my array. But there how to search like sql:

> like % %

Now it search very strong: if i search AC451, it's good, but if AC45 or C451 it's nothing fetches. How to say him so that before and after

> search

could be everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, maybe?

```
 item.ART_ARTICLE_NR.include?(search.upcase)
```

Comment: maybe) also how to delete entries which are in @a from @articles ?

Comment: maybe this is simple? give me only what to give for google? i'm not good in english... ruby delete array intersection or what?

Comment: Why do you want to delete them after all?

Comment: ok, `@`art_concret | `@`articles. can you explaine pross and cons of my (yours) solve, and given by Maciej Litwiniuk

Comment: I never used ransack, so I don't know

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for trouble by not following rails naming conventions an using upper case column names.   That said, the rails3 way to do it is probably:

```
@articles = Article.where(:ART_ID => @search.map(&:ARL_ART_ID)).where('ART_ARTICLE_NR LIKE', "%#{search.upcase}%")
```

Without knowing what @search is, it's hard to be sure.   But you should read up on the [active record guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on the rails 3 query format.

Comment: it's not standart-db, it's huge and no my

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe not straigtforward answer, but have you considered using [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) gem?

Comment: Problem's with english, will speak in known language) Nigdy nie używalem gem'uw do wyszukiwania. jakie są jego zalety?

Comment: Just take a look at it - it provides nice set of wrappers for (almost) every possible search condition. in above example search field will be called art_article_nr_cont.

Comment: I thinks that answer to your problem is here: https://github.com/ernie/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching